# Crosswalk / Equivalence Mapping from HCPCS (Devices) to FDA Product Code

Tags: medical, openfda

Is there any available mapping between the HCPCS-II codes associated with medical devices and the 3-letter FDA "Product Code"?

So to be excruciatingly obvious...

- The [FDA Product Code for Cochlear Implant](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfPCD/classification.cfm?id=1702) is "PGQ"
- The [HCPCS-II code for roughly the same device](https://www.aapc.com/codes/hcpcs-codes/L8614) class/group/type is "L8614"

Is there a cross-walk or equivalence mapping dataset that will let me find "PGQ" given that all I've got is the "L8614"?

Comment: Jay did you ever find an answer to this? We're hoping for a similar solution.